# How to apply a UniqueEntity validation on superclass

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

When defining a abstract superclass with several implementations, I can't get the UniqueEntity check to work.

For example when creating an AbstractUser having an email field and a FacebookUser/TwitterUser, the UniqueEntity check's only the sub-class. Not the parent one.

Any ideas on how to apply the Unique check at top-level?

EDIT : I'm using the `joined` table inheritance with a discriminator column. See [doctrine documentation.](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance)

Comment: is your abstract superclass annotated with the [MappedSuperclass](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#mapped-superclasses) annotation?

Comment: Nope, using the joined table strategy meaning no SuperClass annotation.

Comment: I think FOSUserBundle uses xml because that sort of thing is not possible with annotations.

Comment: Ok, gonna check the bundle then. Thanks for the tip carlosz.

Comment: Nope. Did not found it. The only way I found to check unique email validation is creating an external constraint in which in inject Doctrine and I manually check if the email is unique.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the `entityClass` parameter on the constraint config with the superclass like this:

```
/**
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, entityClass=User::class)
 */
```

Comment: This seems to work as a solution to the original question exactly as expected

Answer (score 1):

You might need to write your own validation constraint to check for uniqueness in this case.

It's logically unclear how the UniqueEntity constraint shall apply in this case. 
Shall all extending classes be checked for uniqueness of the property or only the currently used class?

As UniqueEntity constraint looks for uniqueness of the property in the table the second variant is not covered with the default behavior.
Therefore you can't use the constraint on to the class being extended with single table inheritance currently.

---

**With regard to the question comments:**

FOSUserBundle does not include a UniqueEntity constraint in [config/validaton.xml](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/validaton.xml).

... but it can be found for orm, mongodb, couchdb and propel i.e. in [config/orm/orm.xml](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/validation/orm.xml).

FOSUserBundle uses @MappedSuperClass instead of joined table inheritance.